# DOM code for select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-select

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MfdR4/

I want, if you select a no. then according to that number the rows comes up!

```
var number_opt = document.getElementById("opt_select");
var opt;
for (var i = 1; i <= number_opt.value; i += 1) {
  opt = '"#opt_row_' + i + '"';
  $(opt).show(100);
}
```

Will this work! I know it's stupid!

Comment: Check punctuation of your question. It's not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can...using `change()` event.

try this

```
$(function () {
  $("#opt_row_1,#opt_row_2,#opt_row_3").hide(0);  //<--using multiselector
  $("#opt_select").change(function () {
    var $val = this.value;
    $('#opt_row_' + $val).show(100);

  });
});
```

**update**

if you want to hide other rows before displaying the selected rows then

```
$(function () {
$("#opt_row_1,#opt_row_2,#opt_row_3").hide(0);


$("#opt_select").change(function () {
    $("#opt_row_1,#opt_row_2,#opt_row_3").hide(0);
    var $val = this.value;
    $('#opt_row_' + $val).show(100);

});
});
```

**hide other rows and display the selected rows :** [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/MfdR4/8/)

**simple fiddle displaying just the selected rows** : [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/MfdR4/5/)